# How do I make a sub-mailbox?

Tags: macos, mail.app

How do I create a mailbox within a mailbox in Mail?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new mailbox with **Mailbox -- New Mailbox** you can select where exactly you want to put it.

[image]